# Working with String array in postgresql and java

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm trying to work with sql array. I have inserted String array to database with this method:

```
Array myArray= conn.createArrayOf("text", stringArray);//stringArray:List<String>
preparedStatement.setArray(1, myArray);
```

it will be written successfully like

> {"ddd ggg",ll}

but I can't read result array ! when I'm trying to get this array from database the exception says:

```
Couldn't execute query
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TypeInfoCache.getPGArrayElement(TypeInfoCache.java:390) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.buildArray(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:323) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArrayImpl(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:149) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Array.getArray(AbstractJdbc2Array.java:110) ~[postgresql-9.1-901.jdbc4.jar:na]
```

here is my code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
//query: "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME "    
    Array a= rs.getArray(COL_NAME);
    String[] myArray = (String[]) a.getArray();
}
```

How can I get myArray from database?

Comment: Could you paste the description of your table.

Comment: my bad! the problem was there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error attempting to read a String[] from a Postgresql "text" column. Changing the column from "text" to "text[]" solved the issue.